# How to find the mobile duplication in form using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have create the form with selection option. Based on the selection i show and hide form field.... How to validate the mobile no. If the user enter same mobile no again then throw the error message. How to find the mobile duplication entry

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#hidden-div').hide();
 $("#select_btn").change(function() {
    toggleFields();
  });
  });

function toggleFields() {
  var selectVal = $("#select_btn").val();
  if (selectVal <= 5) {
    $hiddenHtml = $('#hidden-div').clone().html();
    $("#refer").html('');
    for (var i = 0; i < selectVal; i++) {
      $("#refer").append($hiddenHtml);
    }
  }
}

function InvalidMsg(textbox) {

     if(textbox.validity.patternMismatch){
        textbox.setCustomValidity('please enter valid mobile number');
    }    
    else {
        textbox.setCustomValidity('');
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<title> Demo </title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id ="refer-form" name="refer-form"   method="post" >
 
  <p>No of Referrer:
    <select id="select_btn" onchange="toggleFields();">
      <option value="0">--Select--</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <div id="hidden-div">
 <div id="text">Referrer</div>
      <p>Name:
        <input type="text" name="name[]" class="name"/>
      </p>
      <p>Mobile:
        <input type="text" name="mobile[]" class="mobile" oninvalid="InvalidMsg(this);" />
      </p>
      <p>Email:
        <input type="text" name="email[]" />
      </p>
      
    </div>
    <div id="refer">

    </div>
    <p align="center">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use array in input name

like this

```
      <p>Name:
        <input type="text" name="reference_name[]" />
      </p>
      <p>Mobile:
        <input type="text" name="reference_mobile[]" />
      </p>
      <p>Email:
        <input type="text" name="reference_email[]" />
      </p>
```

Comment: you will get array of value of each element

Comment: Hi amit, I need output like Array ( [player_name] => uma [mobile] => 9769956198 [player_email] => ggdfhgd [reference_name] => sakthi2 [reference_mobile] => 989898598859 [reference_email] => hjgjhgjh [City] => Chennai [Course] => B.A ).

Comment: when i change the code as u said.... i got the array value...Array ( [player_name] => sakthi [mobile] => 8888888888 [player_email] => ggdfhgd [reference_name] => Array ( [0] => [1] => sakthi1 [2] => uma1t ) [reference_mobile] => Array ( [0] => [1] => 9769956199 [2] => 9769956190 ) [reference_email] => Array ( [0] => [1] => gfhfh [2] => gfhfh ) [City] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => Mumbai [2] => Mumbai ) [Course] => Array ( [0] => B.com [1] => B.com [2] => MBA ) )

Comment: yes thats only for your hidden div value , you will get array of its .

like in your html you choose two or three then two times div created so you have to itrate for loop for them and gets value from it , thats why suggest to take array of each element okay .. and in forloop you have to count any of the input that has array and drive loop from count try it

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, all your names are different.

Do you want to print them using javascript or php?
If php, you need to add an action to your form. When submitting the form all the values will be sent to your action file and you will be able to get them using $_POST.

So, imagine your file is named join.php. Your form will be 
`<form method="POST" action="join.php">`, it will call itself on submit.
And then you'll be abble to get the values using `print_r($_POST);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to hold all the values of the inputs with `.mobile` class. And if you find a duplicate you can return an error.

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/dpJAXw)**

```
$("#refer-form").on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  mobnos = new Array();
  $(".mobile").each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('duplicate');
    val = $(this).val();
    if($.inArray(val, mobnos) > 0){
      $(this).addClass('duplicate');   
    } else {
     mobnos.push(val);
    }
  });
});
```